# How can I use Perl and RRD to plot ping times?

Tags: perl, rrdtool, rrd

I'm trying to do my first rrd graph through Perl.
I have tried [RRD::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RRD-Simple) and rrds and just can't get either one to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use RRD::Simple ();

# Create an interface object
my $rrd = RRD::Simple->new( file => "server.rrd" );

# Put some arbitary data values in the RRD file for the same
# 3 data sources called bytesIn, bytesOut and faultsPerSec.
 $rrd->create(
            EqSearch => "DERIVE",
            MfSearch => "DERIVE",
            EQCostBasis => "DERIVE",
            MFCostBasis => "DERIVE"
        );

$rrd->update(
            EqSearch => 2,
            MfSearch => 3,
            EQCostBasis => 10,
            MFCostBasis => 15
        );

# Generate graphs:
# /var/tmp/myfile-daily.png, /var/tmp/myfile-weekly.png
# /var/tmp/myfile-monthly.png, /var/tmp/myfile-annual.png
my %rtn = $rrd->graph(
            destination => "/Users/cmuench/Documents/Code/perl",
            title => "Server A",
            vertical_label => "",
            interlaced => "",
            periods => [qw(hour)]
        );
```

The output is:

[graph http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/a39e2bd662adefa823dca66351db637c5g.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/a39e2bd662adefa823dca66351db637c5g.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far, along with your sample output?

Comment: codebin:
http://code-bin.homedns.org/602

and the output png
http://www.mediafire.com/file/4jdrymiyhmm/server-hourly.png

Comment: It's much nicer to make it part of the question on Stackoverflow so it doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

From your above script, the main issue is that you don't have enough data to show in graphs. you can see the data in your rrd using '[rrdtool fetch](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdfetch.en.html)`.

If you can use bash instead of perl. Look at this "[Round Trip and Packet Loss stats with rrdtool](http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2007/03/21/round-trip-and-packet-loss-stats-with-rrdtool/)"

If you still want to use perl module [RRD::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RRD-Simple/lib/RRD/Simple.pm), please look at the examples provided with this module i.e. [RRD::Simple::Examples](http://search.cpan.org/~nicolaw/RRD-Simple-1.44/lib/RRD/Simple/Examples.pod) Or provide more details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Unfortunately I really need to use perl as I have other parts of my script written in perl.  nobody else?

Comment: What are the other parts and what the problem/errors you are facing.

Comment: Well basically I generate the graph but no data is showing up inside them.

Comment: at what frequency you are updating the rrd and how you are getting the ing response. I cant see all this in provided code. I woud like to suggest you to have a look at the bash example i provided and the rrd simple examples. Also look at the RRDTool documentations for data.